# How can I disable VCL Style for PopupMenu/Menu for Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

How can I disable VCL Style for PopupMenu/Menu for Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Because it's not running properly with long menus. So, I want to use windows style for menu/popup menu items.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable the styling of the menus under the VCL Styles you must remove the *shMenus* element of the  [TStyleManager.SystemHooks](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.SystemHooks) property.

```
TStyleManager.SystemHooks := TStyleManager.SystemHooks - [shMenus];
```